# Foreign Keys in Geopackage

Tags: geopackage

How to create foreign keys and cardinality in a Geopackage with QGIS or FME? It's easy to get the tables, but how can I set the relations between the tables?

Comment: GeoPackage is a SQLite database so you can start by reading documentation in https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html and tutorial https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-foreign-key/. You can use any SQLite admin application.

Comment: Thanks. I figured there might be a QGis tool/plugin since it's supposedly the new standard format.

Comment: Related tables do not belong to GeoPackage core. Have a look at this extension http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/18-000/18-000.html#_gpkgext_relations. It is brand new and I suppose that QGIS does not support it yet.